# Detecting Human Voice within Gamemaker Audio data

Tags: audio, pcm, game-maker

I am writing a game that I need to filter out data coming from the microphone to determine if it contains human voice. The data is 16 bit PCM. Is there existing code out there that does this? Or at least some pseudocode that is close that could be implemented to do this?

Comment: I'm not hopeful, but you might get more help at a forum that specializes in digital signal processing (dsp).

Comment: AnHave you tried the proposed solution? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider going with [RNNoise](https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise), a noise suppression model. What is of interest to you is the VAD: Voice Activity Detector. For your purpose, you could discard the noise suppression part and use VAD alone. Values close to 1 indicate voice, 0 otherwise. It's a robust system with a very good performance.

You might consider modifying the neural network to only output VAD and simplifying the model accordingly. That's assuming you want